# How can I reveal my site's sub-menu for mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reveal my sub-menu using jQuery. It is a  rewrite of the code in the image using jQuery.

https://github.com/alwayswantedtocode/xpress-cars-web-dev-

Code I am trying to rewrite using jQuery:

[image: code I am trying to rewrite using jquery]

```
$(document).on("click", ".navigation", function(event) {

  const target = $(event.target),
    mediaSize = 991;
  homeSubList = $(event.target.parentElement),
    revealSubMenu = $(homeSubList).add('.sub-menu');

  if ($(target).attr("data-toggle") && (window.innerWidth <= mediaSize)) {
    $(homeSubList).toggleClass("active");

    $(revealSubMenu.height()) = $(revealSubMenu).prop('scrollHeight') + 'px';
  };
});
```

Comment: Please don't ever post code as an image. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```js
$(document).on("click",".navigation", function(event){
  const mediaSize = 991;
  if ($(event.target).attr('data-toggle') !== undefined && window.innerWidth <= mediaSize) {
    const menuItemHasChildren = $(event.target).parent();

    $(menuItemHasChildren).addClass('active');
    const subMenu = $(menuItemHasChildren).find('.sub-menu');
    $(subMenu).css('maxHeight', $(subMenu).prop('scrollHeight'));
  }
});
```